# When running ldifde, I'm missing the objectSid values. How do I get those to be returned?

Tags: active-directory, export, ldif

I'm able to generate an LDIF export of my active directory like this

```
ldifde -f test-data.ldif
ldifde -f test-data2.ldif -d "CN=Configuration,DC=domain,DC=com"
```

I then combine these two files together and I have a pretty useful exported LDAP tree.

But when I look into the exported data, the one bit of glaringly missing data is the objectSid values, which are supposed to be exported by default (no need for the `-l` parameter).

Why is that missing? What can I do to get that included in the export?

So anything such as TokenGroups or anything involving an SID is not working from the exported data.

If I run:

```
ldifde -f test_objectsid.ldf -d "dc=domain,dc=com" -p subtree -r "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=User)(givenname=*))" -l "objectSid,objectSids,cn,givenName,objectclass,samAccountName"
```

This **does** contain objectSids. So what is going on with my first `ldifde` command?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up being super simple.

My first command just needed to explicitly add `-l` parameters. Without it, I wasn't getting them.

```
ldifde -f test-data.ldif -l "objectSid;binary,objectSids,cn,givenName,objectclass,samAccountName,distinguishedName,memberOf,userPrincipalName,primaryGroupID"
```